# How in tailwindcss table hide column on small devices?

Tags: tailwind-css

With tailwindcss 2 I want to hide some columns in the table on small devices using `sm:hidden`:

```html
<table class="table-auto">
  <thead class="bg-gray-700 border-b-2 border-t-2 border-gray-300">
    <tr>
      <th class="py-2">Name</th>
      <th class="py-2">Active</th>
      <th class="py-2">Type</th>
      <th class="py-2 sm:hidden">Category</th>
      <th class="py-2 sm:hidden">Mailchimp Id</th>
      <th class="py-2"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td class="">
        Name content
      </td>
      <td class="">
        Active content
      </td>
      <td class="">
        Typecontent
      </td>

      <td class="  sm:hidden">
        Category content
      </td>

      <td class="sm:hidden">
        mailchimp content
      </td>
```

I expected that on devices 640px and smaller 2 columns would be hidden,  but failed.

Which syntax is correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tailwind uses a mobile first breakpoint system, meaning, if you use `hidden` class, it will affect all the screen sizes. But if you attach a prefix such as `sm`, `md`, `lg`, `xl` and `2xl` it will target the corresponding screen size and above it. You can read more about it [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design).

For example, using `sm:hidden` will only hide the element on sm and above screen size. So, you could combine it together such as, `hidden md:table-cell` it will not show on screen size lower than `sm` breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks! But after some testing looks like I need "hidden md:table-cell".  Looks like table uses "table-cell" ?

Comment: Right, I just realize it's a table. I have updated my answer. Could you mark the answer as answered please.

Answer (score 2):

as a more general answer, not regarding table cells, another display type can be chosen to overwrite hidden.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/display

example:

```html
<p class="hidden lg:flex">Only visible on larger than lg</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an example.

```html
<table class="whitespace-nowrap">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Active</th>
      <th class="hidden md:table-cell">Type</th>
      <th class="hidden md:table-cell">Category</th>
      <th class="hidden lg:table-cell">Mailchip</th>
      <th class="hidden lg:table-cell">other</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name content</td>
      <td>Active content</td>
      <td class="hidden md:table-cell">Type content only in md</td>
      <td class="hidden md:table-cell">Category content only in md</td>
      <td class="hidden lg:table-cell">Mailchip content only in lg</td>
      <td class="hidden lg:table-cell">other content only in lg</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And here you have all the **display** properties to play around with a bit more. (Remember to combine it with the hidden property + the responsive variants `sm:`, `md:`, `lg:`, `xl:`, `2xl:`)